# Assign static variable to non-static variable

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Consider the Base class where A class and BaseB class are derived. From BaseB is derived C class. All clases inherit non-static variable “y” but in the case of BaseB and C class “y” have the same value.
I resolved this situation with the following code:

```
class Base {
    protected:
        int y;
    virtual void registerValue()
        {
        y = 5;
        }

};

class A : public Base {
};

class BaseB : public Base {
    protected:
    static int x;
        virtual void registerValue()
        {
          // Process x ...
          y = x;
        }

};

class C : public BaseB {

};

int BaseB::x = 3;

int main() {}
```

It works but is it right to assign static variable to non-static variable for this case?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be. It's the assignments *to the static variable* that you have to watch out for (concurrency issues, etc.)

Comment: "All clases inherit non-static variable “y” but in the case of BaseB and C class “y” have the same value"  -  well, they ALL have the same value of Y; apart from sometimes you set it to different values.  ie. if you make a call to `B or C :: registerValue` you will end up changing the value for A, which is probably not what you desire.

Comment: UKMonkey take into acount that Class A generate other instance with its own member y.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine to do from a language legality perspective, but it's a little odd.

Presumably you can't make `Base::y` `static` since that would interfere with the behaviour of class `A`?

You just need to be aware of the fact that instances of `BaseB` will all share the same `x`, but could have different values of `y`. Is that the intended behaviour?

Personally I'd consider making `void registerValue()` a pure virtual function in the base class, and *expect* all derived classes to implement that method including all necessary storage for its implementation. Perhaps that necessitates a base class function `virtual int getRegistedValue() = 0` too?

Comment: Yes Bathsheba I can't make Base::y static because in the case of the  A Class the "y" variable is different. With static x with assure that x will be the same for the clases BaseB and C and as a consequence we will have the same value for y in these classes

Comment: For the implementation is not required to implement virtual int getRegistedValue() = 0.